# Count the number of lines in a PDF file in PHP

Tags: php

In a PHP script, I would need to count the number of (text) lines in a PDF file. How can I do that? I cannot seem to find any answers on Google.

The PDF files I am interested in are templates for bindings of master theses (created and uploaded by users). I do not expect to find paragraphs of text in there, rather just single lines spread across a single page.

Comment: Define "lines". What if the PDF file has multiple columns, or text blocks? If it's at all possible (which it may not be), it is not likely to be possible in pure PHP. I'd look for external solutions (e.g. command line tools) and then call those from PHP

Comment: I edited the question to give some information on the expected type of PDF files. If the PDF file had multiple columns, or text blocks, then I suppose I would need to get the sum of lines in each of those.

Comment: I see. It may be impossible - I don't know. Do you know a tool that does this on *any* platform? All the solutions I can see after a quick search are tools that fake line count (by assuming each line is x characters long).

Comment: You might be able to convert it to HTML with a command line tool, and then simply count the `<br />`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short suggestion which might work. First of all have a look at this link http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html. It is a pdf to txt converter. If you know the text size you can calculate the line over this script.

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('file.pdf');
echo $a->output();
...
Calculate how many lines the file contains
```